# How to catch error in gulp final callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, gulp

I am trying to run certain tasks in `gulp`.
And I want that if any error occurs in any task, it should show it immediately via my `callback function`. Here is the code:

```
var callback = function(err) {
    if (err)
        showError(err)
    else
        done();
}

gulp.task('default', ['myWebpackTask', 'mySassTask', 'myOtherTask'], callback);
```

Note: I don't want to use following syntax:

```
gulp.src("./somepath/entry.js").pipe(webpack()) .......
```

Just take that all my tasks are async functions that do not make use of `gulp.src` syntax

Is it possible in Gulp?

Comment: You cannot pass a callback function to `gulp.task()`. That makes no sense conceptually. You should probably explain what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve, [instead of trying to guess what the solution will look like](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I have rephrased my question. Happy?